# How to open all subclasses of a type in Eclipse IDE?

Tags: java, eclipse

I usually use Ctrl + T (*Quick Type Hierarchy* on the right-click-menu) on a class declaration to see a list of it's subclasses in a window popup.

The problem with this popup is that it's only possible to open up a subclass at a time. I cannot seem to use shift and block all of the class' subclasses and open all of their editors on the IDE.

For now, i have to keep reminding myself what is the last opened subclass and start opening the next subclass.

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try using `F4` to see the type hierarchy.

Comment: Yes, i have tried this, but i cant seem to select multiple subtypes also in the left panel of the Type hierarchy in my Indingo. Do you have a different experience with this issue ?

Comment: I see multiple subtypes, if I have an interface, it will show each class implementing that interface.

Comment: I can see all the subclasses too. But the problem is that i want to open all the subclasses to edit those files. I think that holding shift and select all works on the subclasses and press enter to open all, but it doesnt work.